# 401 Unauthorized Error After Upgrading Tomcat from 10.0.22 to 10.0.23

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-401, tomcat10

I recently upgraded my Tomcat server from version 10.0.22 to 10.0.23. Since this upgrade, I'm encountering a 401 Unauthorized error during API calls between my client and server. This issue is observable in the access logs.

Key details:

**Authentication Method**: The server-client authentication is managed through certificates.
**Configuration Files**: All configuration files remained unchanged post-upgrade.
**Troubleshooting Attempts**: I have used both tcpdump and Wireshark to diagnose the issue, but I couldn't locate the specific API call in these logs. access_log doesnt give more info. only the url of tha"HTTP/1.1" 401 146".

Given that the server setup and authentication method haven't changed, I'm puzzled about the cause of this 401 error post-upgrade. Could someone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?